# i need to get value on button click from dynamic control which was generated

Tags: c#, asp.net

There have many controls are Generated I want to save value on button  click which is dynamically generated on page,Can any one Help me to this. I am new in this field so i m using many types of code from code but it cant ...

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
            {

              CreateDynamicForm(Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]));
            }
        }
    }

    protected void CreateDynamicForm(int id)
    {
        DataTable dt = objDl.FetchList(id);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                string text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["ControlToDisplay"]);
                string chkval = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["IsActive"]);
                if (text == "Checkbox")
                {
                    CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
                    chk.ID = "Checkbox" + i;
                    string ID = chk.ID;

                    chk.Attributes["style"] = "margin-left: 87px;line-height: 3;";
                    if (chkval == "True")
                    {
                        chk.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chk.Checked = false;
                    }

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FieldLabel"]);

                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(chk);
                    Literal lt = new Literal();
                    lt.Text = "<br />";
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lt);  

                    hdnID.Value = hdnID + "," + ID;
                    HdnType.Value = HdnType + "," + "Checkbox";
                }

                if (text == "Dropdownlist")
                {
                    int j = 0;
                    DropDownList ddlList = new DropDownList();
                    ddlList.ID = "DdlDisplay" + i;
                    ddlList.CssClass = "form-group";
                   // ddlList.CssClass = "col-sm-3";
                    ddlList.Attributes["style"] = "margin-left: 96px;width: 151px;padding-left: 43px;";
                    string texts = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["OptionValue"]);
                    string[] txtcount = texts.Split(',');
                    foreach (var items in txtcount)
                    {

                        if (items.TrimStart().TrimEnd() != "")
                        {
                            j++;
                            ListItem ltm = new ListItem();
                            //ltm.Attributes["style"] = "padding-left: 43px;";
                            ltm.Value = "Listitem" + j;
                            ltm.Text = Convert.ToString(items);

                            //ddlList.Items.Add(txt);
                            ddlList.Items.Add(new ListItem(ltm.Text, ltm.Value));

                        }
                    }

                    hdnID.Value = hdnID + "," + ddlList.ID;
                    HdnType.Value = HdnType + "," + "Dropdownlist";



                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FieldLabel"]);
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(ddlList);

                    Literal lt = new Literal();
                    lt.Text = "<br />";
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lt);
                }

                if (text == "SingleLineTextBox")
                {

                    TextBox textb = new TextBox();
                    textb.ID = "TextBox" + i;
                    textb.Attributes["style"] = "margin-left: 87px;";
                    textb.Attributes["required"] = "true";


                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FieldLabel"]);
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(textb);

                    Literal lt = new Literal();
                    lt.Text = "<br />";
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lt);

                    hdnID.Value = hdnID + "," + textb.ID;
                    HdnType.Value = HdnType + "," + "SingleLineTextBox";
                }

                if (text == "Multiline Textbox")
                {

                    TextBox textMulti = new TextBox();
                    textMulti.ID = "MultiTextBox" + i;
                    textMulti.TextMode = TextBoxMode.MultiLine;
                    textMulti.Attributes["style"] = "margin-left: 87px;margin-top: 16px;";
                    textMulti.Attributes["required"] = "true";

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FieldLabel"]);
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(textMulti);

                    Literal lt = new Literal();
                    lt.Text = "<br />";
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lt);

                    hdnID.Value = hdnID + "," + textMulti.ID;
                    HdnType.Value = HdnType + "," + "Multiline Textbox";

                }

                if (text == "RadioButton")
                {
                    RadioButton rdb = new RadioButton();
                    rdb.ID = "rdb" + i;
                    rdb.Attributes["style"] = "margin-left: 87px;line-height: 4";

                    Label lbl = new Label();
                    lbl.Text = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[i]["FieldLabel"]);
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lbl);

                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(rdb);

                    Literal lt = new Literal();
                    lt.Text = "<br />";
                    panelDynamic.Controls.Add(lt);

                    hdnID.Value = hdnID + "," + rdb.ID;
                    HdnType.Value = HdnType + "," + "RadioButton";
                }

            }
        }
    }

    protected void btn_submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question. Do you want to save a dynamically generated value?

Comment: Yes,,On btn_submit_Click how to get all value from dynamic controls

Comment: Dynamic controls need to be (re)created on every postback, so move it outside `if (!IsPostBack)`

Comment: Sorry for Delay, Actually i m recreating that control on Page Init in that case we get all the ID's of dynamic control but there have one issue.....Issue is that in dynamic control checkbox and Radio button are also present but in page init that ID cant fetch if checkbox and radio button is checked ID are fetch but if it is doesn't check ID are not found...So,Can u help me............................................................................................................List<string> keys = Request.Form.AllKeys.Where(key=>key.Contains("MainContent_")).ToList();